# Sharepoint 2013 health and usage data

Tags: sharepoint-2013

i am new to SharePoint and we have a SharePoint 2010 setup  wherein we were using these queries on the SP MS SQL DB  to fetch results for our purpose :

```
select * from wss_logging.dbo.siteinventory
select * from wss_logging.dbo.featureusage
select * from wss_logging.dbo.requestusage
```

Now we are planning to use SharePoint 2013 and the same queries fail there citing invalid object name .

Do we need to enable any feature to enable such logging or the object names/views have changed in SP 2013 ?

Any help would be  greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried investigating your event logs? You might need to enable the feature + set the right database permissions. Also, why do you need the queries? You can view them in Sharepoint Administration :)

Comment: @Gudgip , i enabled it under central admin --> monitoring --> usage & health data collection.This worked fine for SP 2010 , however for SP 2013  i could see the other 2 default views but SiteInventory was still at large :(

Comment: And your IIS Server Event viewer?